# Power Query From Folder as Merge, Not Append

Tags: powerquery

I need to import multiple files from a folder and I need each file's contents to be new columns in the resultant table.
There are multiple examples all over the web of how to include multiple files from a folder as an append (e.g., [PowerQuery multiple files and add column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110679/powerquery-multiple-files-and-add-column)) but I need the contents of each file to be merged as new columns in the original table.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with my own answer. Once you append the files you can pivot on the file name to turn them into columns.